# how to get all features from a layer in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms

I deal with geoserver and openlayers,
i use WMS layer for displaying due to loading time is shorter than vector layer.

My problem i couldn't get all features of a layer without event,
For sure i tray "getfeatureinfo" but it's return selected point not all
And i try to use vector layer for getting the features, But it not work unless i add it to the map ,
which will take long long time in loading .!

could any one help?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: get features.length and access specific feature (Features[0].time).

Comment: @Reem; I have the same problem, I use `ol.layer.Tile` and `ol.source.TileWMS`. were you able to get all the features of the clicked layer, instead of just the one feature being clicked?? thanx